# Convert number to date sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert a number (`yyyymmdd`) to date (`mm/dd/yyyy`)

For example

```
20150302 ====> 03/02/2015
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try this:

```
select to_date(20150302,'yyyymmdd') from dual;
```

or

```
select to_char(to_date(20150302,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual;
```

Comment: `20150302` is a **NUMBER** not a **string**. `TO_DATE` accepts string. You are forcing Oracle for an implicit datatype conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)** function to convert `NUMBER` to `DATE`. Try in following:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(20150302, 'YYYYMMDD') FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Probably because `to_date()` only accepts character literals (aka "strings"), not numbers `20150302` is a number, not a string.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's not correct. to_date() does accept number as well. Execute the following query and and see it yourself: select to_date(20150302,'yyyymmdd') from dual;

Comment: @Sen: see [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118): the first parameter for `to_date()` is declared as `char`. There is no version of `to_date()` that accepts a number. If you call it with a number, the evil implicit data type conversion will convert that number to a `varchar` before calling to_char.  So `to_date(20150302,'yyyymmdd')` is silently executed as `to_date(to_char(20150302),'yyyymmdd')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what you are saying about the implicit conversion is correct. But that is not the point here, the point is whether that function accepts number or not. As one can see, it does not matter what happens behind the scenes(implicit conversion).

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is still incorrect.
It returns a character string when a date is needed.
The correct way is:

```
select to_date(to_char(20210416), 'YYYYMMDD') num_to_char_to_date from dual;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not sure why this was downvoted (I upvoted it). My only suggestion to improve your answer would be to include the actual output of running your solution. For one, this proves it works, but also explains more clearly that there is also an alias for the output.

Comment: This was downvoted because it is a comment on another answer disguised as a legitimate answer. Comments on answers should not be posted as answers.

Answer (score 0):

**TO_DATE** accepts char of `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR2` datatype and converts into a value of **DATE** datatype.

So, convert the number into string, and apply to_date. You could use **single-quotation marks** around the number to convert it into **string**.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('20150302', 'YYYYMMDD')  FROM dual;
```

Remember, a DATE has no format, what you see is for display purpose. If you want to display the date in a desired format, then use **TO_CHAR** along with your desired format model.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20150302', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM dual;
```

Read more about [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

Comment: but why yuor queries are not working for SELECT TO_DATE('1', 'YYYYMMDD')  FROM dual;

Comment: @nikhilsugandh How is '1' a valid date even? And, "not working" is not an Oracle error message.

Comment: I was checking for this select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(1,'J'),'JSP')from dual;

Answer (score 0):

To convert in the required format:

```
select to_char(to_date(20150302, 'YYYYDDMM'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

`select to_char(to_date(20220912, 'YYYYDDMM'), 'YYYYMMDD') from dual`