# How to change a number column to a date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a number column that shows seniority dates like this '20150802' and would like to see the output in a mm/dd/yyyy format.  How would I go about converting the number column to a date column?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have a case statement like this...

Comment: CASE
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) <= 3   THEN '0-3 Months'
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) <= 6   THEN '3-6 Months'
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) <= 12  THEN '6-12 Months'
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) <= 24  THEN '1-2 Years'
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) <= 36  THEN '2-3 Years'
    WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(tl.BUSINESS_DAY, tl.SENIORITY_DATE) >  36  THEN '3+ Years'
    ELSE NULL
  END as TENURE_HIRE_DATE,

Comment: But I get an error that it is not a valid month

Comment: How would i work around that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert number to date sql oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405833/convert-number-to-date-sql-oracle)

Comment: What you wrote in the comment is not related to this question. You'd better asking a new question in which `input` and `output` sample values should be clearly stated besides this query.

Answer (score 4):

You can use such a conversion as below :

```
select to_char(to_date(20150802,'yyyymmdd'),'mm/dd/yyyy')
       as "Converted Date"
  from dual;

Converted Date
--------------
08/02/2015
```

*P.S. You can switch `dd` and `mm` among then in the format. Since I don't know whether `02` or `08` is `month` or `day` respectively.*

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column is a `number` and that it represents dates like `'yyyymmdd'`, you may need:

```
select to_char(to_date(to_char(yourColumn), 'yyyymmdd'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: @RB_29 . . . The outer `to_char()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Gordan I tried removing it, but doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The [NUMTOYMINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions130.htm#SQLRF00683) and [NUMTODSINTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions129.htm#SQLRF00682) functions and some arithmetic will give the desired result.

```
select 
  to_char(date'1-1-1' +
    NUMTOYMINTERVAL(trunc(n / 10000) - 1, 'year') +
    NUMTOYMINTERVAL(trunc(mod(n, 1000) / 100) - 1, 'month') +
    NUMTODSINTERVAL(mod(n, 100) - 1, 'day'),
    'mm/dd/yyyy') as s
from (select 20150802 as n from dual) t
```

**Output:**

```
S
----------
08/02/2015
```

Comment: A bit overkill I would say.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, the question is a bit vague to give on it a simple and clear answer :)